# Efficiency in Mechanism Design - Myerson-Satterthwaite

Tags: game-theory, social-choice-theory, auction-theory

I was reading some online notes on the 4 conditions that cannot all hold given the Myerson-Satterthwaite theorem and this definition of efficiency confused me:

> An efficient mechanism selects the choice that maximizes the
>   sum of agents’ utilities, disregarding monetary payments. Also known as social welfare maximization.

The part about disregarding payments confused me because shouldn't this be taken into account in order to determine the outcome that maximizes social welfare?

Mathematically, a mechanism is efficient if in equilibrium, the outcome $x$ satisfies: $$\sum_i v_i(x) \geq \sum_i v_i(x')$$
For all players $i$ and all other possible outcomes $x'$.

Comment: Don't most of these problems assume utility is quasi-linear in money? So $i$'s utility from outcome $x$ and receiving a transfer of $t_i$ units of money is: $v_i(x) + t_i$?  In this case, since the system is closed $\sum_i t_i = 0$?

Comment: Yes that is assumption is applicable here (I believe), so what you're saying is seeing as the net payments is zero including the auctioneer for example (no subsidies or loss), we can disregard them anyway and just focus on the valuations?

Comment: I'd think so. Without seeing the notes you were reading it's hard to say more clearly, but I'd imagine the intuition is something to that effect (i.e. potentially the total supply of money is some fixed constant $t$, possibly zero, and hence is killed off on both sides of the inequality you present).

Comment: Pete Caradonna's comment is right on spot. I am ready to bet a (reasonable) amount that your notes assume quasi-linearity of the utility functions wrt money.

Comment: I can confirm they do. Makes sense to me now. Feel free to write this up as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: @tbone I have put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition of efficiency assumes that utility functions are quasi-linear in money. Hence, payments cancel and may be ignored.